# Chained getattr method calls

Tags: python, getattr, chained

let say i have

```
  class Blah:
    def __init__(self):
       self.foo = ...
       self.bar = ...
```

**foo** and **bar** does NOT implement **getattr**.
And they dont have attr "abc" and "xyz"

Is it possible to trick it to do

```
  b = Blah()
  x = b.foo.abc
  y = b.bar.xyz
```

OR

```
  x = b.abc.foo
  y = b.xyz.bar
```

---

foo and bar may not even exists i.e. sort of virtual

Comment: Why would they need to implement `getattr`? As long as `b.foo` has an `abc` attribute it will work.

Comment: What are the values you're assigning to `self.foo` and `self.bar`?

Comment: it doesnt matter what i assign .. i want to intercept the access to their getattr .. thats why i'm ok with the reverse syntax too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. When you do

```
x = b.foo.abc
```

it's essentially equivalent to

```
temp = b.foo
x = temp.abc
```

When you're using `.abc`, there's no reference to the `Blah` instance any more, you're just getting it from whatever value was stored in the `foo` attribute. So if that value doesn't have an `abc` attribute or `__getattr__` method, you'll get an error.

There's no way for `Blah` to intercept the access to the next level below its attributes.

Comment: ;(  .... got idea :) I may then use underscore instead of dot

Comment: If you use underscore then it's just one attribute, not an attribute of an attribute.

Comment: yes...not perfect... but this work for me